# Passing a vector to a template function

Tags: c++, templates, vector

Here is a small function I'm trying to write to keep track of the dynamic allocations I use in my functions (tired of writing delete [] all the time).

```
template <class T>
T* snew(int size, vector<T*> list)
{
    T* pointer = new T[size];
    list.push_back(pointer);
    return pointer;
}

vector<float*> list;
float* myfloat1 = snew<float*>(HEIGHT*WIDTH,list);
float* myfloat2 = snew<float*>(HEIGHT*WIDTH,list);
float* myfloat3 = snew<float*>(HEIGHT*WIDTH,list);
```

So then when I need to clear the memory I can use:

```
template <class T>
void sdelete(vector<T*> list)
{
    vector<T*>::iterator it;
    for (it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it){
        delete [] *it
        *it = NULL
    }
}
```

like this:

```
sdelete<float*>(list);
```

When I try to compile I get:

```
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty,_Ax>'
```

Not sure what it means. Thanks for the insight :)

Comment: Use vector of vectors or Boost.MultiArray if you want a multidim array.

Comment: Have you considered using a smart pointer or just using one of the Standard Library containers for this?  You shouldn't need to be writing `delete` all over the place in application code; if you are doing that, it's likely your code is incorrect and not exception safe.

Comment: as @James mentioned, smart pointers might be what you need. [`boost::shared_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) is a nice one eg.

Comment: @Sander, why isn't `vector<float>(WIDTH*HEIGHT)` a good container?

Comment: Why didn't you use a vector to store the data? Instead of a vector to track the data? Odd.

Comment: @unkulunkulu : I never said it wasn't. But if the only goal is to avoid doing `delete`s, then smart pointers seem like a good idea to consider as an alternative approach. If it's not applicable for this specific case, then at least it's in @Smash's tool belt now.

Comment: I use arrays since the functions I interact with use arrays, unless you tell me that function expecting array pointers also accept vectors ?

Comment: And for the smart pointer thing, I think I remember reading that the delete is done without the [] so they won't work in the case of arrays (unless I'm wrong)

Comment: @Smash for the function expecting `float *` you can pass `&vec.front()`, where `vec` is `vector<float>`. This is acceptable and safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First and foremost, you pass `vector<T*> list` by value, which means that it gets copied and your global `list` is left unchanged.

Do it like this:

```
template <class T>
T* snew(int size, vector<T*>& list)
```

As for the compilation issue, there's a typo, you're applying `*` one time too much, change the usages to

```
float* myfloat1 = snew<float>(HEIGHT*WIDTH,list);
sdelete<float>(list);
```

Or you could even rely on compiler's type inference and just write

```
float* myfloat1 = snew(HEIGHT*WIDTH,list);
sdelete(list);
```

But the idea as a whole is pretty much a bad one, because if you have a `vector` already, you don't want to do `new/delete` by hand. Just create a `vector<float> x(HEIGHT*WIDTH);` and use it, it gets removed automatically.

Comment: ok, so a vector is a type like any other type, not a pointer, so if I want to pass it by reference I need to do &, ;)

Comment: And note that when you read & pasted the compilation error `cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty,_Ax>'`, you forgot to include the template parameters in it (which are specified afterwards, or on the next line). They would have revealed this issue to you instantly!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
snew<float>(HEIGHT*WIDTH,list);
```

or better, simply

```
snew(HEIGHT*WIDTH,list);
```

Indeed, the template argument `snew` is `T`, and you pass `vector<T*>`. To match `vector<float*>`, you must pass `float`.

When calling function templates however, arguments can be deduced, so you don't need to put the `<float>` thing at all.

However, the best advice I can give you is to forget about all this and use `vector<vector<float>>`.

Comment: i see you mean since I specify T* in my function definitions, I don't need to say T*, but only T in the call